# CSS media query won't select header tag, but it will select the header element by its ID

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

Why is this happening?

https://codepen.io/headonshoe/pen/dyorVVg

see the codepen, the `header` is the first element in the HTML body, and the media query is at the very bottom of the CSS

Comment: you have obvious errors in your html use w3 validator to check

Comment: Wow I didn't know that existed. It didn't really address my issue but it's awesome to know about nonetheless! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector in the regular styles list for the header is `#header` , in the media query you use `header` as a selector for the rule there.

Although both apply to your `<header id="#header">` element, the first one (`#header { ...}`) is more specific, since it uses the ID and therefore will not be overruled by the `header { ...}` rule in the media queries.

Use the same selector in both rules to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select only the tag `<header>` in css you have to write header without hashtag like this (# its for id and . for class):

```
header {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "logo . end";
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: I understand, perhaps you misunderstood the question? I have no problem selecting the header the in CSS just by its tag. The regular CSS is great. Its the media query that's giving me trouble. When I try to select the header tag in the media query, things don't work until I give it an ID and select it by its ID.

Comment: it's happening because of CSS Specificity. You have select in the begining with #. if you select all without # you will see, it will work. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

"The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
ID selectors (e.g., #example)."

Comment: Got it, I hadn't realized I selected it in the "regular" CSS by its ID. Thank you!!